# struct pcap_pkthdr len always == zero

Tags: c++, pcap, libpcap

Without copying all of the source in here, I am hitting a `pcap_callback` function from `pcap_dispatch`. The `caplen` seems to show the correct length (being that it is always something) but the len always equals 0. Is this field no longer populated? Is this maybe an error condition I am not capturing?

Here is a snippet...

```
void myCallback ( const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet, void* buffer )
{
   if ( (uint16_t)(header->len) != (uint16_t)(header->caplen) )
       /* Some Error */
        streamObj << "Caplen (" <<  (uint16_t)(header->caplen) <<  " != "
        << ") Packet Len (" << (uint16_t)(header->len) << ")";
   ...
}
```

The `header->len` value always comes back as zero. If more info is needed, just let me know.

This was found on a SUSE Linux 11SP1 server running libpcap.so.0.9.8 with a 2.6.32 kernel. The issue is only present after upgrading from SUSE Linux 10SP3 with libpcap.so.0.9.3.

EDIT: 
    This appears to only be an issue with libpcap.so.0.9.8. I repointed the link in /usr/lib/ to use libpcap.so.0.9.3 and the problem disappeared.

Comment: I suggest you to watch the memory pointers you're getting back!

Comment: @sarat. Normally I would agree with you. However, the header pointer is one that is populated by libpcap. I don't really have control over what ends up in there.

Comment: @user953665 If you're down to something that is so specifically version-sensitive, and no notes in the documentation about this behavior changing on purpose, then you may need to build libpcap from the source...then step into the function calls to get your answer.  Full source code for old versions available here: http://www.tcpdump.org/release/

Answer (score 0):

The three arguments to a callback function for `pcap_dispatch()` are, in order:

1. The "user data" pointer passed to `pcap_dispatch()`;
2. A pointer to a `struct pcap_pkthdr`;
3. A pointer to the raw packet data.

Therefore, `myCallback` is not a valid callback function, and can't be passed to pcap_dispatch(), as it's expecting the first argument to be the pointer to the `struct pcap_pkthdr`.  Unless you have another function that's the real callback, which then calls `myCallback` with the appropriate arguments, the code in question won't work, and should get at least a warning from a C or C++ compiler.